# javascript-How to detect scroll event in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a problem when I try add event scroll with iframe tage. generally, I use scroll event with div tag It was working well. but when I add scroll event in iframe tag to detect user scroll pdf page, It was not working. why cannot I access html elements in iframe?, I have code inspect below:

[image]

**and I try to add javascript scroll event with iframe :**

**HTML Code:**

```html
<iframe id="myframe" src="doc.pdf"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```js
document.getElementById('myframe').onscroll = function(){
   alert('scrolling page');
};
```

Answer (score 13):

An `iframe` does not have a scroll method, the `document` of the `iframe` does - you need to reference the inner `document` rather than your `<iframe>` tag.

You can reference it with `iframe.contentDocument` and add a scroll even listener:

```
iframe.contentDocument.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  console.log(event);
}, false);
```

#### Edit August 2023:

Reading the contents of an `iframe` is subject to the [Same Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) policy, so this method only works if the `iframe` content is part of the same protocol and URL as the host document. Otherwise, `iframe.contentDocument` will return `null`. This is defined in the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement).

Comment: so, if I want to use with pdf, should I use with  any one ( object, embed, iframe) ?

Comment: can't get the iframe.contentDocument, it's null

Comment: your snippet is not working :(

Comment: The snippet no longer works because StackOverflow changed the URL of where they host the snippets, and reading the contents of the iframe is subject to the Same Origin policy. This method still works otherwise - I will update the answer.

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript provide us **onscroll** as an attribute which passes parameters (Can be a function). But we got iframe here, try the following code snippet (jQuery).

```
$("#yourFrameId").load(function () {
     var iframe = $("#yourFrameId").contents();

    $(iframe).scroll(function () { 
        //your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: what is different from contents() with contentDocument ?

Comment: Sure. 
The contentDocument property returns the Document object generated by a frame or iframe element only.
Whereas contents() method allows us to search through the immediate children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the issue and here's one of my implementation.

```
var currAgreementTab = this.get('parentController').get('currAgreement');
var contractContainer = Ember.$('div#marginContractContainer');
var iframe = contractContainer.children(currAgreementTab.element)[0].contentWindow;

if (iframe) {
  iframe.onscroll = function() {
    var scrolledHeight = Ember.$(iframe).height() === Ember.$(iframe.document).innerHeight() ? Ember.$(iframe).height() : Ember.$(iframe.document).innerHeight() - Ember.$(iframe).height();

    if (Ember.$(iframe).scrollTop()  === scrolledHeight) {
      var currAgreementTab = that.get('parentController').get('currAgreement');
      Ember.set(currAgreementTab, 'checkDisabled', false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks